# Newtonsoft Deserialization and Properties Getter Method

Tags: c#, json-deserialization

Newtonsoft's json Deserializer, `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);` was deserializing my object wrong because it would not instantiate one of the properties. I wrote up a [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NnIyJE) which shows the same problem.

Classes:

```
public class Right
{
    private Property _property;
    public Property Property 
    { 
        get { return _property; } 
        set { _property = value ?? new Property(); } 
    }
}

public class Wrong
{
    private Property _property;
    public Property Property  
    { 
        get { return _property ?? new Property(); } 
        set { _property = value; } 
    }
}

public class Property
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Main Program:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //Instantiate
        var right = new Right();
        var wrong = new Wrong();

        //Initialize property
        right.Property = new Property() { Text = "Right!" };
        wrong.Property = new Property() { Text = "Wrong?" };

        //Serialize
        var jsonRight = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(right);
        var jsonWrong = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(wrong);

        //Print json
        Console.WriteLine(jsonRight);       
        Console.WriteLine(jsonWrong);

        //Deserialize
        var dRight = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Right>(jsonRight);
        var dWrong = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Wrong>(jsonWrong);

        //Print property
        Console.WriteLine("'" + dRight.Property.Text + "'");
        Console.WriteLine("'" + dWrong.Property.Text + "'");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
// {"Property":{"Text":"Right!"}}
// {"Property":{"Text":"Wrong?"}}
// 'Right!'
// ''
```

Why can't the Deserializer do its thang when I'm doing `return _property ?? new Property();` inside the getter method?

Answer (score 4):

Because -

```
public class Wrong
{
    private Property _property;
    public Property Property  
    { 
        get { return _property ?? new Property(); } // no assignment done to _property.
        set { _property = value; } 
    }
}
```

This creates a new property whenever the property is null. But it does not update the `_property` member, it is still the old one and still the null one. So, every time you use the property it creates a new object and returns it and forgets the reference when it runs out of scope. If does not matter whether you are using `Json Converter` or anything. **This is a very very very destructive appoach**.

The right approach is this one -

```
public class Right
{
    private Property _property;
    public Property Property 
    { 
        get { return _property; } 
        set { _property = value ?? new Property(); }  //initialized and assigned to _property
    }
}
```

It initializes the property with new object if it is null and assigns to the member `_property`. In future whenever you use this property, it has the proper reference and works properly.

**BTW: This is not a problem. This is the required behavior.**

Comment: I understand what is happening in the code. And I understand that the `Right` class is better. I still don't understand how the `Wrong` class "breaks" deserialization. Doesn't it access the setter method?